# v-model updated in code but not on screen using Vuetify.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I have a problem:
I have 4 fields in a `data` object: `contact_id`, `contact_child_id`, `address_id,` `address`.

When `contact_id` OR `contact_child_id` OR `address_id` are changed, the `address` is updated.

**Problem**
If I `console.log(data.address)`, it is updated but the input field displayed is not.

I need to be able to manually change the address, add some information, so I cannot use computed property

Template:

```html
    <v-autocomplete
                v-model="data.contact_id"
                :label="$tc('Contact')"
                :items="contact.items"
                :loading="contact.loading"
                :search-input.sync="contact.search"
                autofocus
                return-object
              ></v-autocomplete>

              <v-select
                v-model="data.contact_child_id"
                :items="child.items"
                :loading="child.loading"
                :placeholder="$tc('Contact')"
                return-object
                @change="updateAddress"
              >
                <template v-slot:item="data">
                  <template>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title>{{data.item.name}}</v-list-item-title>
                      <v-list-item-subtitle>{{data.item.job}}</v-list-item-subtitle>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </template>
                </template>
              </v-select>

              <v-select
                v-model="data.address_id"
                :items="addressItems"
                :loading="addressLoading"
                return-object
                @change="updateAddress"
              >
                <template v-slot:item="data">
                  <template>
                    <v-list-item-content>
                      <v-list-item-title v-html="nl2br(formatAddress(data.item))"></v-list-item-title>
                    </v-list-item-content>
                  </template>
                </template>
              </v-select>
            </v-card-text>
            <v-card-text>
              <v-textarea
                v-model="data.address"
                auto-grow
                rows="1"
                :label="$tc('Address')"
              ></v-textarea>
            </v-card-text>
```

Script

```js
    function updateAddress() {
          data.value.address =
            (typeof data.value.contact_id == "object"
              ? data.value.contact_id.name
              : props.contactName) +
            (typeof data.value.contact_child_id == "object" &&
            data.value.contact_child_id.name
              ? "\n" + data.value.contact_child_id.name
              : "") +
            (typeof data.value.address_id == "object"
              ? "\n" + formatAddress(data.value.address_id)
              : "");
          console.log(data.value.address);
        }
```

The `console.log(data.value.address)` prints for example `organization\ncontact name\naddress` but the input field does not display the change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're facing an issue of reactivity as mentioned [`here`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects) , so you should use `context.set(data.value,'address',theValue)` :

```
setup(props,context){
...
 function updateAddress() {
          context.set(data.value,'address',
            (typeof data.value.contact_id == "object"
              ? data.value.contact_id.name
              : props.contactName) +
            (typeof data.value.contact_child_id == "object" &&
            data.value.contact_child_id.name
              ? "\n" + data.value.contact_child_id.name
              : "") +
            (typeof data.value.address_id == "object"
              ? "\n" + formatAddress(data.value.address_id)
              : ""));
          console.log(data.value.address);
        }

...
}
```

or destruct the context as follows :

```
setup(props,{$set, ...}){
...
 function updateAddress() {
         $set(data.value,'address'
```

Comment: I didn't know that, I will give it a try

Comment: the instance methods like `$refs, $emit , $set` which are accessed like `this.$emit` in vue 3 could be accessed like `context.emit`

Comment: I can't get it work. My setup is like setup(props, { root: { $i18n, $vuetify, $route } })... so I can't use context(...) or should I not destructure context

Comment: in the second parameter you're destructing the context object, so you could add the set method as : `{ $i18n, $vuetify, $route,set }` and use it `set(`data.value,'address',...)`

Comment: Thanks for your help, it does work. My setup is :  setup(props, { emit, root: { $set } })...